# How does the compareTo(K) method in Java really work?

Tags: java, compareto

I am pretty new to Java so I need some input from you guys.

I am trying to use the `compareTo()` Java method and it works fine when comparing single digit numbers but when comparing a single digit number to a number of more than one digit, it doesn't work as expected. Here's an example:

```
data[0] = 10;
data[1] = 5;

Input : if( data[0].compareTo(data[1]) > 0)
        then swap (using temp)

output: data[0] = 10
        data[1] = 5
```

Note if `data[0] = 8`(for example) it works fine.

Comment: while the compareTo method takes any object the logic is based on strings.

Comment: I am trying to do removal on priority queue which the lowest key called and removed. In this case, I am using an array type K. I tried to use < or > sign but didnt work since this is a comparable data type, I guess.. any clue?

Comment: Post some real code to start with.

Comment: @kpie: What's your source for the idea that "the logic is based on strings"? The behavior of the `compareTo()` method depends on its implementation and doesn't necessarily have anything to do with strings at all.

Comment: @Evansiauw: Your question is completely abstract, but the answer depends on the type of the objects in your `data` array. You need to provide a [mcve] so that people here can help you.

Comment: I was about to publish an answer in the post you just deleted...

Comment: hi alfasin, sorry, I was thinking to repost.. but anyway I already undelete the post.. feel free to post your answer.. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your problem:**

You are using `compareTo` which is a **method**. You may not be aware of this, but the primitive class `int` does not have any methods. All of it's methods are contained inside the wrapper class `Integer`. When trying to call the methods from an `int` you are bound to run into problems like this.

So, when using `compareTo` you have to be comparing two integer objects.

Example:

```
Integer intA = new Integer("10");
Integer intB = new Integer("25");
```

Once you have actual integer objects, you can then use the `compareTo` method... Such as this:

```
int sol = intA.compareTo(intB);
```

But when comparing `int`, not the wrapper class, you should really just use syntax like this:

```
int intA = 5;
int intB = 10;
int sol = intA-intB;
```

It's much simpler and easier to understand.

**Background on the compareTo method:**

What the `compareTo` method does is return a value less than, equal to, or greater than 0. As you probably already know. But, the `compareTo` method is part of the `Comparable<E>` interface, meaning **How it works depends on the implementation**.

Some classes, such as `int` and `String` already implement the `Comparable<E>` interface, meaning they have their own way of utilizing the `compareTo` method...

String's `compareTo` method uses numerical representations for individual strings... I do not know exactly how it calculates these values, but it does it alphabetically. So for a String, a word starting with an A would have a lesser value than a word starting with a B.

For integers the `compareTo` method is pretty straight forward, since they already have numerical values.

If you want to learn more about the `Comparable<E>` interface, here's a little example:

```
public class Weight implements Comparable<Weight>
{
   private int myPounds, myOunces;

   public Weight()
   {
      myPounds = myOunces = 0;
   }
   public Weight(int x, int y)
   {
      myPounds = x;
      myOunces = y; 
   }

   public int getPounds()
   {
      return myPounds;
   }
   public int getOunces()
   {
      return myOunces;
   }

   public int compareTo(Weight w)
   {
      if(myPounds<w.getPounds())
         return -1;
      if(myPounds>w.getPounds())
         return 1;
      if(myOunces<w.getOunces())
         return -1;
      if(myOunces>w.getOunces())
         return 1;
      return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Always prefer `Integer.valueOf(...)` rather than `new Integer(...)` since that allows you to reuse an existing `Integer` object if it has the right value rather than always allocating a new one.

Comment: Also, because the original question says it "works fine" with some values but not with others, there's probably not a compile-time error. That means that the objects in question are probably already `Integer` objects, not primitive `int` values.

Comment: I see your point... But I also tried to create a new integer value, and use that inside the `if-statement` that way if it was some obscure syntax error with his compiler, then it might not happen.

Comment: You suggest "int sol = intA - intB;". That will work in most cases, but give strange results with big numbers, as e.g. 2000000000 - (-2000000000) gives -294967296 in 32-bit integer calculation, although the mathematical result should be positive. Integer.compare() etc. handle that case correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It returns value > 0 if first object "greater" than second, 0 if it is "equals" and < 0, if it is "less".

I use quotes to mark that for objects, you need to tell java how to define what's a "greater" and what's "less" using `Comparator` object.

Comment: So the input is an array (K comparable data type). If inputs are 8 4 6 3 1 2 output would be 1 2 3 4 6 8. But if you add let say 12( more than 1 digit value). output would be 12 1 2 3 4 6 8.. the 12 supposed to be after  8

Comment: @Evansiauw, it may happens because of Integer&#39;s compareTo() implementation, but it just an theory. Why you do not use data[0] > data[1]? U sort integers so it should works fine

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answers.. I think I've figured out what's wrong with my program.. The input is saved as string so I need to use Integer.parseString method before using the compareTo method.. that's why when comparing 10 and 5.. 10 comes first than 5